# Mapping Sharepoint Drives

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but it's my understanding that a sharepoint run website (such as a business's intranet) can be mapped to a network drive. You could theoretically access that drive and get documents from it OR upload documents to that drive and it would update the sharepoint run website with the new document.

I have no experience with this and it seems like a very neat thing to do. I only have some experience with creating sharepoint webpages and some security regarding those webpages (so, not very advanced).

How do I go about enabling sharepoint webpages to do this? I don't really even know what to look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a SharePoint site is accessible to employees, they can map a drive letter to the UNC filepath of a SharePoint site, library, or folder.

The UNC path requires dropping the `http` protocol prefix and flipping all forward slashes to backslashes.

For example, if you have a SharePoint library that can be accessed at `http://contoso.sharepoint.com/mycoolsite/mycoollibrary`, users can map a drive letter to `\\contoso.sharepoint.com\mycoolsite\mycoollibrary` to open that library in Windows Explorer.

Accessing a SharePoint site via Windows Explorer does require the WebClient service to be running on the user's computer. It uses the WebDAV publishing model to treat SharePoint directories as if they were PC folders. This service does have some limitations that you wouldn't run into when using SharePoint in the browser. For example, by default it can only move files up to 50Mb; this is a registry setting on the user's computer, not a SharePoint limitation.

Note that users do not need to map a drive letter to use this functionality; they can navigate to `\\contoso.sharepoint.com\mycoolsite\mycoollibrary` in Windows Explorer directly. Mapping a drive is sort of equivalent to bookmarking the location for easy access.

Comment: For admins, here is a tool that helps with mapping: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Map_Document_Libraries_as_Network_Shares